# Set Notation Probability

Tags: probability

[image]

I don't understand how I would do this question when it does not have any values to work with.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You have the number of cards in the deck ($52$), the number of suits in a card deck ($4$), and the number of different card values ($13$). Suits are like hearts, diamonds, spades, and clubs. The values are $A$, $2$, ..., $9$, $J$, $Q$, $K$.

Comment: Oh ok... sorry, I don't really know much about cards, the decks and stuff... @anakhronizein I'm surprised they expect us kids to know that

Comment: Don't be sorry. Now you know!

Comment: Would the probability be $0/52$ or $1/52$ for (a)? I understand it means 'Q' intersect 'D' but the Queen of Diamonds is seen only once however none of decks contain Q//D twice? @anakhronizein

Comment: Note that $P(Q\cap D)$ is the same as saying the "probability that a card is a queen $and$ a diamond". So as you pointed out, that occurs $1$ time. The total number of cards is $52$, so the probability is $1/52$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a standard deck of cards there are $52$ cards, $4$ different suits (hearts, diamonds, clubs, and spades), and $13$ different values for the cards ($A$, $2$, $3$, ..., $9$, $J$, $Q$, $K$).

Additionally, each suit has a colour. Hearts and diamonds are red, and clubs and spades are black.

---

Now just an explanation of notation:

Suppose we have two events, $A$ and $B$.

When we say $P(A \cap B)$, we are saying the "probability that both events $A$ **and** $B$ occur".

When we say $P(A \cup B)$, we are saying the "probability that events $A$ **or** $B$ occur".

For example:

In a), you are asked for $P(Q \cap D)$. This is like asking for the probability that a card you choose is **both** a queen **and** a diamond. As you previously stated in a comment, this occurs only once because there is only one queen of diamonds in the deck of cards. So you have $1$ card out of $52$ total in a deck that you can choose. Simply, that is a probability of $1/52$.

Likewise, in b) you are asked for $P(Q \cup D)$, which is like asking for the probability that a card you choose is a queen **or** a diamond.

I will leave the rest up to you, but if you need help, don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 1):

Let's do an example, part (a). Part (a) asks for the probability that a random card is queen diamond. Since there is only one such card and 52 cards in total, the probability is 1/52.

Part (b) asks for the probability that a random card is a queen or a diamond; part (c) asks for the probability that a random card is *not* a queen or is a diamond; and part (d) asks for the probability that a random card is a queen other than queen diamond. In all cases, the answer is N/52, where N is the number of cards satisfying the requirements.